# VM can’t connect to outside in bridged mode

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am not able to ping any machine(not even the host) from Guest VM in bridged mode. But I got an IP which is on the same subnet as host. I can ping my guest VM from the host and can use ssh to connect to the guest.

I am using Vmware workstation 6.5. Guest VM is a centos VM and host is windows xp.

Every thing works fine in NAT mode. Any clues as to what could be happening. I tried disabling all the firewalls I have.

My virtual network editor shows that my ethernet adapter(the one my host uses) is used for bridging. It is connected. I don't understand how I can get an IP address from DHCP server.
I can't ping any of the DNS servers in generated /etc/resolv.conf which are the same as that of my host

Answer (score 1):

Read [*How to Enable TCP/IP Forwarding in Windows XP*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315236).

By default, TCP/IP forwarding is not enabled in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping any outside **IP**  (not the *name*)? Maybe just the DNS resolution is b0rken in your guest OS